# Entering 40000 rows in sql server through loop

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, loops, random

I have to make a database system that is purely on SQL Server. It's about a diagnostic lab. It should contain at least 40,000 distinct patient records. I have a table named "Patient" which contains an auto-generated ID, Name, DOB, Age and Phone number. Our teacher provided us with a dummy stored procedure which contained 2 temporary tables that has 200 names each and in the end he makes a Cartesian product which is supposed to give 40,000 distinct rows. I have used the same dummy stored procedure and modified it according to our table. But the rows inserted are only 1260 every time. Each time we run the query it does not give us more than 1260 records. I have added a part of temporary name tables and the stored procedure.

```
Declare  @tFirstNames Table( FirstName Varchar(50) Not Null )
Declare @tLastNames Table ( LastName Varchar(50) Not Null )
Declare @tNames Table ( Id Int Identity Not Null, Name Varchar(50) Not Null)
Insert Into @tFirstNames (FirstName)
    Select 'Julianne' Union All Select 'Sharyl' Union All Select 'Yoshie'
    Union All Select 'Germaine' Union All Select 'Ja' Union All
    Select 'Kandis' Select 'Hannelore' Union All Select 'Laquanda' Union All
    Select 'Clayton' Union All Select 'Ollie' Union All
    Select 'Rosa' Union All Select 'Deloras' Union All
    Select 'April' Union All Select 'Garrett' Union All
    Select 'Mariette' Union All Select 'Carline' Union All


Insert Into @tLastNames (LastName)
    Select 'Brown' Union All Select 'Chrichton' Union All Select 'Bush'
    Union All Select 'Clinton' Union All Select 'Blair'
    Union All Select 'Wayne' Union All Select 'Hanks'
    Union All Select 'Cruise' Union All Select 'Campbell'
    Union All Select 'Turow' Union All Select 'Tracey' 
    Union All Select 'Arnold' Union All Select 'Derick' 
    Union All Select 'Nathanael' Union All Select 'Buddy' 

Insert Into @tNames
Select  FirstName + ' ' + LastName
    From @tFirstNames, @tLastNames

Declare @iIndex Integer
Declare @iPatientTotalRecords Integer
Declare @vcName Varchar(50)
Declare @iAge Integer
--Set @iIndex = 1
Select @iPatientTotalRecords = Max(Id), @iIndex = Min(Id) From @tNames

While @iIndex <= @iPatientTotalRecords
Begin

    Select @vcName = Name From @tNames Where Id = @iIndex
    Set @iAge = Cast( Rand() * 70 As Integer ) + 10
    Insert into Patient values
        (@vcName, @iAge,
            Case Cast( Rand() * 3  As Integer)
            When 0 Then 'Male'
            When 1 Then 'Female'
            Else 'Female'
            End,
            Cast( Rand() * 8888889 As Integer ) + 1111111, DateAdd ( year, -@iAge, GetDate()))

    Set @iIndex = @iIndex + 1
End
```

Comment: The problem is that the stored proc is supposed to add 40,000 rows but it always stops at 1260.

Comment: Use the SSMS built-in debugger or add print statements to see what happens at runtime. Just looking at the code is not a good problem solving strategy.

Comment: I don't know what SSMS is.

Comment: If you mean de-bugging the proc, then I have already tried that. The proc doesn't run in that mode. And this same proc and Names table worked for other groups' projects.

Comment: SSMS=SQL Server Management Studio.  it is basically an IDE for SQL Server, where you can edit queries, run them, and see their output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible you miss type UNION ALL -

```
Select 'Julianne' Union All 
Select 'Sharyl' Union All 
Select 'Yoshie' Union All 
Select 'Germaine' Union All 
Select 'Ja' Union All
Select 'Kandis' --<-- missing union all
Select 'Hannelore' Union All 
Select 'Laquanda' Union All
Select 'Clayton' Union All 
Select 'Ollie' Union All
Select 'Rosa' Union All 
Select 'Deloras' Union All
Select 'April' Union All 
Select 'Garrett' Union All
Select 'Mariette' Union All 
Select 'Carline'
```

**Try this one (without WHILE and additional variables):**

```
DECLARE @tFirstNames TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @tFirstNames (FirstName)
VALUES 
    ('Julianne'), ('Sharyl'), ('Yoshie'), ('Germaine'), 
    ('Ja'), ('Kandis'), ('Hannelore'), ('Laquanda'), ('Clayton'), 
    ('Ollie'), ('Rosa'), ('Deloras'), ('April'), ('Garrett'), 
    ('Mariette'), ('Carline')

DECLARE @tLastNames TABLE (LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @tLastNames (LastName)
VALUES 
    ('Brown'), ('Chrichton'), ('Bush'), ('Clinton'), 
    ('Blair'), ('Wayne'), ('Hanks'), ('Cruise'), ('Campbell'), 
    ('Turow'), ('Tracey'), ('Arnold'), ('Derick'), 
    ('Nathanael'), ('Buddy') 

INSERT INTO dbo.Patient (...) 
SELECT 
      -- Possible problem: String or binary data would be truncated 
      d.FLName -- <-- FirstName + LastName i.e. 50 + 1 + 50 = 101 chars
    , d.Age
    , Gender = CASE ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(NEWID(), NEWID())) AS INT)) % 3
                    WHEN 0 THEN 'Male'
                    ELSE 'Female'
               END
    , (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(NEWID(), NEWID())) AS INT)) % 8888889) + 1111111
    , BirthDay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD( year, -d.Age, GETDATE()), 112)
FROM (
    SELECT 
          FLName = f.FirstName + ' ' + l.LastName
        , Age = (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(f.FirstName, NEWID())) AS INT)) % 70) + 10
    FROM @tFirstNames f
    CROSS JOIN @tLastNames l
) d
```

Comment: Please give some time and I try to help you improve it.

Comment: (206 row(s) affected)

(210 row(s) affected)

(43260 row(s) affected)
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 235
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

This is the error I get and now it is entering 5460 rows. Line 235 is "Insert into Patient"

Comment: what data types are in the table "Patient"?

Comment: Hey @Mike Thanks. Your solutions worked. The problem was in my Patient attribute "Name" which was set as char(10) by mistake.